# HTML5 video not playing only in chrome

Tags: html, wordpress, html5-video

i am using this code to play a video in a wordpress website.
the code workes perfectly in all browsers but in chrome controls are disable and the video is not playing.
any where else but that site the code works in chrome.
changing the theme and disabling plugins did not solve the problem.i have changed the code and the format of videos several times but nothing works on that.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
<source src=" test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />;
  <source src=" test.ogv" type="video/ogg" />;
  <source src=" test.webm" type="video/webm" />;
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the problem really was ssl.
I just activated ssl on my download host and the video played nice and easy.
thank you so much for your hint rank. if this link was not: [https://w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video)
i still was searching for the problem on my website.

Comment: This is the REAL answer. On Chrome html5 video won't start IF SSL certificate is invalid ! Pay attention. I was on this problem for days. If you develop a wordpress site and activate SSL without a valid certificate html5 video will not works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried eding the syntax?

You should definately delete the semicolons after the source tags. This is Html, not a javascript code, so there should be no semicolons.

Also you can set the boolean attribute of controls with giving no value, simply put the "controls" inside the tags.

Give this a try, maybe it solves your problem with chrome:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src=" test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src=" test.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src=" test.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

Comment: I tried this code but the problem is still there. the code works in another website or even in  a simple html page but it does not work in one specific website.

Comment: Well if the code is working anywhere else, you should let us take a look at your specific website, because the problem seems to be there. Do you get any errors in the console or something like that? How do you include this code to your wordpress site?

Comment: no there is no error. i just write the code inside the text editor in a post or product page

Comment: Can you provide a link? So I could check how the bahivour is in the other browsers and in chrome...  do you consider using a plugin? they will take care of the browser compatibility https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/html5-video-player/

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: the video is not on auto play mode also the code works everywhere except in one specific website.

Comment: I think you will have to give us some more information about the one specific page, in which the code is not working. Seems obivous that it is something in the page, that keeps the code from working. Maybe you have something different to the other sites, another page template or header, some script calls or a sidebar .. .?

Comment: it is not just one page. there is no difference between a post page or a product page or even footer the code does not work for chrome.i have tried all of them.

Comment: This works fine in chrome: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video  with the controls being displayed. Does this also work when you use the link? If it works, I guess there has to be other code involved that causes the problem.

Comment: the code is not working in w3 editor but when i copy the code in a simple empty html page it works.

Comment: Have you updated your chrome browser and checked, if you have any browser extentions activated? It should definately work in the w3 editor, no matter which browser you are using (which is not outdated). I've tested it with chrome, firefox, edge, safari, working like a charm.

Comment: the chrome is on latest version. my files are located in a download host with a subdomain with no ssl, but the website itself is on another host with ssl for domain. can this cause the problem?

Comment: If you want to display data that is located at a place with no ssl on a site with ssl, the browser will alert that there is insecure content in this page. The user will get a warning, I would suggest to change this setting, because you can't use it in production. maybe this also can cause the problem, you're right...

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered, but a note on your source files.  Browsers select the first file they "know how to play".

Since every [browser that supports video also supports mp4](https://caniuse.com/#search=mp4), you'll never actually see any playback of the ogg or webm versions of the video.  I would suggest:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src=" test.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src=" test.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src=" test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />  
</video>
```

(and since webm and ogg fully overlap - you can probably save yourself from creating the ogg files altogether)

Comment: thank you so much for sharing your idea. for now i only use x264 mp4 format because it works on all browsers.